# The optimal way to set a breakpoint in the Python source code while debugging CPython by GDB

Tags: debugging, gdb, cpython

I use **GDB** to understanding how **CPython** executes the `test.py` source file and I want to stop the **CPython** when it starts the execution of opcode I am interested.

**OS:** Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
**Debugger:** GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3) 8.1.0.20180409-git

---

**The first problem** - many CPython's `.py` own files are executed before my `test.py` gets its turn, so I can't just break at the `_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault` - there are many of them, so I should distinguish my file from others.

**The second problem** - I can't set the condition like "when the filename is equal to the **test.py**", because the filename is not a simple `C` string, it is the CPython's Unicode object, so the standard **GDB** string functions can't be used for comparing.

At this moment I do the next trick for breaking the execution at the needed line of `test.py` source:

For example, I have the source file:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']

# I want to set the breakpoint at this line.

for e in x:
    print(e)
```

I add the binary left shift operator to the code:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']

# Added for breakpoint   
a = 12
b = 2 << a

for e in x:
    print(e)
```

And then, track the `BINARY_LSHIFT` opcode execution in the `Python/ceval.c` file by this **GDB** command:

```
break ceval.c:1327
```

I have chosen the `BINARY_LSHIFT` opcode, because of its seldom usage in the code. Thus, I can reach the needed part of `.py` file quickly - it happens once in the all other `.py` modules executed before my `test.py`.

I look the more straightforward way of doing the same, so 
**the questions:**

1. Can I catch the moment the `test.py` starts executing? I should mention, what the `test.py` filename is appearing on different stages: parsing, compilation, execution. So, it also will be good to can break the **CPython** execution at the any stage.
2. Can I specify the line of the `test.py`, where I want to break? It is easy for `.c` files, but is not for `.py` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea would be to use a C-extension, to make setting C-breakpoints possible in a python-script (similar to [`pdb.set_trace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.set_trace) or [`breakpoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint) since Python3.7), which I will call `cbreakpoint`.

Consider the following python-script:

```
#example.py
from cbreakpoint import cbreakpoint

cbreakpoint(breakpoint_id=1)
print("hello")
cbreakpoint(breakpoint_id=2)
```

It could be used as follows in gdb:

```
>>> gdb --args python example.py
[gdb] b cbreakpoint
[gdb] run
```

Now, the debuger would stops at `cbreakpoint(breakpoint_id=1)` and `cbreakpoint(breakpoint_id=2)`.

Here is proof of concept, written in Cython to avoid the otherwise needed boilerplate-code:

```
#cbreakpoint.pyx
cdef extern from *:
    """
    long long last_breakpoint_id = -1;
    void cbreakpoint(long long breakpoint_id){
         last_breakpoint_id = breakpoint_id;
    }
    """
    void c_cbreakpoint "cbreakpoint"(long long breakpoint_id)


def cbreakpoint(breakpoint_id = 0):
    c_cbreakpoint(breakpoint_id)
```

which can be build inplace via:

```
cythonize -i cbreakpoint.pyx
```

If Cython isn't installed, I have uploaded a version which doesn't depend on Cython (too much code for this post) on [github](https://github.com/realead/cbreakpoint/blob/master/README.md).

It is also possible to break conditionally, given the `breakpoint_id`, i.e.:

```
>>> gdb --args python example.py
[gdb] break src/cbreakpoint.c:595 if breakpoint_id == 2
[gdb] run
```

will break only after `hello` was printed - at `cbreakpoint` with `id=2` (while `cbreakpoint` with `id=1` will be skipped). Depending on Cython version the line can vary, but can be found out once gdb stops at `cbreakpoint`.

---

It would also do something similar without any additional modules:

1. add `breakpoint` or `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` instead of `cbreakpoint`
2. `gdb --args python example.py` + run
3. When `pdb` interrupts the program, hit `Ctrl+C` in order to interrupt in gdb.
4. Activate breakpoints in `gdb`.
5. continue in `gdb` and then in `pdb` (i.e. `c+enter` **twice**).

A small problem is, that after that the breakpoints might be hit while in `pdb`, so the first method is a little bit more robust.

Comment: The second method doesn't work. I did steps № 1,2 and got `pdb`'s command line, hit `Ctrl+C` and got **Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.** message. The Python's program, that have been under debugging, was interrupted completely by `Ctrl+C`, so there is nothing to debug after that.

Comment: I am trying to test the first method, but by using the plain C extension, because I don't understand **Cython** at all. Thanks for ideas.

Comment: @MiniMax No "Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt" is exactly what you need - after that program is interrupted. You need to input c+enter (for `continue`) for letting gdb run and then **additionally**  `c+enter` for letting pdb run.

Comment: @MiniMax you can install `cbreakpoint` from the provided github-link or rewrite it yourself as C-extension - however for  the solution with `cythonize` there is no more to it than installing cython, saving the given code as cbreakpoint.pyx and calling cythonize - the resulting so can be used whenever needed.